# How To customize the selection of multiple items in a surfaceListBox

Tags: wpf, listbox, drag-and-drop, pixelsense, multi-touch

I have a surfaceListBox that contains many items.
when I put the SelectionMode to multiple , every thing is fine and I click on an item to add it to the selectionItems,
But I want to get the same behaviour but not with clicking on the items but when the touch is moving over the item , 
Here is some details of the manipulation I want to add:

if the touch is moving over a surfacelistboxitem , this item is added to the selectedItems .
Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

SurfaceListBox doesn't support this because it needs to treat moving fingers as scrolling.

If you don't need the ability to scroll, you can ditch SurfaceListBox and instead use a StackPanel filled with SurfaceToggleButton elements.  On those toggle buttons, set ClickMode=Hover so that they will toggle just by moving your finger over them.

-Robert (former PM for the Surface controls)

Comment: Thanks Robert for this Answer, But I can not use other control , I have to use a SurfaceListBox to create the drag and drop for other issues. When I use Stack panel withe toggle button I will loose the functionality of drag and drop and I will have to customize the scroll on the stackpanel.

Comment: you can use the SurfaceDragDrop APIs with any control - it's not tied to SurfaceListBox in any way